# Fetching two attributes of a xml file using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xlink

I have a xml file which has a tag as below:

```
<locator xlink:type="locator" xlink:href="https://www.google.co.in/" xlink:title="Google" xlink:show="replace" xlink:actuate="onRequest" xlink:role="website" rank="1"> </locator>
```

There are many locator tag in the xml file with different roles and rank .

I am able to get the role of the above tag using  `@*[local-name()='role'`.

Now I need to get the rank attribute based on the role. 
Is there any way to fetch two attributes and there values together?

I am new to Xpath . Please help me with this.

Comment: can you show us a sample of your XML.

Answer (score 1):

Well `//locator[@xlink:role = 'website']/@rank` (with a suitable binding of the prefix `xlink` to the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink`) is an example of selecting the `rank` attributes of `locator` elements where the `role` is `website`.

Comment: Thank you Martin. my xml file has the namespace  http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink. But with //locator[@xlink:role = 'website']/@rank I am not able to get the rank of website role.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to get the role of the above tag using
>   `@*[local-name()='role'`.
>
> Now I need to get the rank attribute based on the role. Is there any
>   way to fetch two attributes and there values together?

**Use**:

```
ExprStartYouDidntShow/@*[local-name()='role' or name()='rank']
```

**where** `ExprStartYouDidntShow` **is the expression selecting the elemen(s) whose two attributes should be selected**.

Or, if you need to get these two attributes only when the `role` attribute has a particular value -- say `"wantedValue"`, use:

```
   ExprStartYouDidntShow/locator[@*[local-name() = 'role'] = 'website']
                         /@*[local-name()='role' or name()='rank']
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. I am able to fetch both the role and rank attribute. But I need to fetch rank of a particular role attribute.

Comment: @user1386685: I updated my answer with expression for this new requirement -- in the future, please define better your questions.

Comment: I tried with the updated code. Still not working. I tried like this: "//locator[@role='definition']/@*[local-name()='role' or name()='rank'] " .

Comment: @user1386685: It is impossible to comment on this as you haven't provided any source XML. Also, just saying "it is not working" isn't helpful.

Comment: @user1386685: I updated the expression, now it is selecting the wanted attributes.

Comment: Its working fine now. I apologies for not providing enough info. Next time I will provide the necessary info. Thank you very much

Comment: @user1386685: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Could you, please, accept the answer (by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer)?